# Django Rest List() Error with multiple serializers

Tags: django, rest, serialization

Im trying to create a `Question` Model Serializer. The Question model has several other models that inherit from it like `RangeQuestion`, `YesNoQuestion`, etc..

This is my view:

```
class QuestionViewSet(generics.ListCreateAPIView):
    """
    A viewset that provides `create` actions.
    """
    queryset = Question.objects.all()

    def get_serializer_class(self):
        if 'type' in self.request.data:
            if self.request.data['type'] == 'range':
                return serializers.RangeQuestionSerializer
            elif self.request.data['type'] == 'open':
                return serializers.QuestionSerializer
            elif self.request.data['type'] == 'multiple_choice':
                return serializers.MultipleChoiceQuestionSerializer
            elif self.request.data['type'] == 'yes_no':
                return serializers.YesNoAnswerSerializer
            elif self.request.data['type'] == 'object':
                return serializers.ObjectQuestionSerializer
        else:
            return serializers.QuestionSerializer

    def create(self, request):
        if 'type' in self.request.data:
            serializer = self.get_serializer(data=self.request.data)
            print serializer
            serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
            serializer.save()
            headers = self.get_success_headers(serializer.data)
            return Response(
                serializer.data,
                status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED,
                headers=headers)
        else:
            return Response(status=HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST, data="Must specify a question type")
```

And this are my serializers:

```
class QuestionSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    type = serializers.SerializerMethodField()

    def get_type(self):
        return settings.QUESTION_TYPES['open']

    class Meta:
        model = Question
        exclude = []


class YesNoQuestionSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    type = serializers.SerializerMethodField()

    def get_type(self):
        return settings.QUESTION_TYPES['yes_no']

    class Meta:
        model = YesNoQuestion
        exclude = []


class RangeQuestionSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    type = serializers.SerializerMethodField()

    def get_type(self):
        return settings.QUESTION_TYPES['range']

    class Meta:
        model = RangeQuestion
        exclude = []


class QuestionChoiceSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = QuestionChoice
        exclude = []


class MultipleChoiceQuestionSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    choices = QuestionChoiceSerializer()
    type = serializers.SerializerMethodField()

    def get_type(self):
        return settings.QUESTION_TYPES['multiple_choice']

    class Meta:
        model = MultipleChoiceQuestion
        exclude = []
```

When I acces the url of the list action I get the error:

```
get_type() takes exactly 1 argument (2 given)
```

Can anyone tell me how to make the list view show all the question serialized according to the subclass?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `def get_type(self)` method should be defined `def get_type(self, instance)` because rest framework serializers will pass in the instance as the first argument.